# Accessing HTTPS using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to access HTTPS website using Selenium WebDriver. I'd like to do this without showing browser window.

```
DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.htmlUnit();
capability.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(capability);
driver.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure"/);
```

And I always end up with this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.createHttpClient(HttpWebConnection.java:554)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.getHttpClient(HttpWebConnection.java:518)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.getResponse(HttpWebConnection.java:155)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseFromWebConnection(WebClient.java:1486)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponse(WebClient.java:1403)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:305)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:374)
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.get(HtmlUnitDriver.java:366)
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.get(HtmlUnitDriver.java:355)
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Moreover**, as djangofan states in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578023/using-personal-ssl-certificates-with-webdriver-selenium-2-0), it could be achieved using `TrustEverythingSSLTrustManager`. If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the more than one reference in the Build path.
I have got the same issue as mentioned above.
I have refered http-client-4.1 and selenium-rc.jar 
I remove the http-client,comms and logging. Then it works.