# How to import SSL certificates for Firefox with Selenium [in Python]?

Tags: python, ssl, selenium, webdriver, certificate

Trying to find a way to install a particular SSL certificate in Firefox with Selenium, using the Python WebDriver and FirefoxProfile.  We need to use our own, custom certificate which is stored in the computer running the WebDriver, so the ideal solution would look like this:

```
profile = get_my_profile()
profile.importCertificate('/my/certificates/my_cert.cert')
driver = new webdriver.Firefox(profile=profile)
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5633035/322909)

> Webdriver has no built in mechanism for adding a personal cert.
>
> If you are using firefox the only way that I have found to do this is
>   to create a firefox profile and add the certificate to it. You can
>   then either reuse the profile when you run your tests OR, and this is
>   my prefered option, take the cert8.db and key3.db files and add them
>   to the profile that webdriver creates at runtime. - [Derek Ekins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/98078/derek-ekins)

although the next answer provides a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10017559/322909).