# Is it possible to import a .p12 or .pfx file to Selenium Webdriver using exclusively code?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, e2e-testing

Good Mornin' y'all!!

I've encountered with a problem when I was trying to write one of my e2e test.

I'd like to log in in my application using a certificate, I don't know if it's possible to add this certificate using only code, I've been googling it for some days searching for some info, but I've only encountered a solution where you add your certificate to a testing profile in your browser and then you switch to that profile, but it's not suitable for me, so...

It's possible to add a certificate using a local file in Selenium Webdriver?

Thanks for your answers!

PS: Maybe using capabilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5633035/322909)

> Webdriver has no built in mechanism for adding a personal cert.
>
> If you are using firefox the only way that I have found to do this is
>   to create a firefox profile and add the certificate to it. You can
>   then either reuse the profile when you run your tests OR, and this is
>   my prefered option, take the cert8.db and key3.db files and add them
>   to the profile that webdriver creates at runtime.

Comment: That was what I thought but maybe in StackOverflow someone could know a litle bit more than me ^^U

Comment: just have a look at the other comments in the linked answer. Not sure if it might help you or not. But a testing profile is working quite well :)