# PFX certificate with Selenium with python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, certificate

It seems that the problem of using pfx certificate files with Selenium is loading a [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50578437/is-it-possible-to-import-a-p12-or-pfx-file-to-selenium-webdriver-using-exclusi). However, this questions and related ones are quite old now, so I was wondering if there is an way to submit a pfx (or a pem , as is possible in the post method of requests) on a click method.

If it is not possible, is there any way to programmatically generate a firefox profile with python and "install" a pfx certificate on it?